# how to access enterprise events using Java code

Tags: long-polling, box-api

I was told by box support that the current box Java SDK doesn't support enterprise admin event. It does support long poll regarding a single user's event at this moment.  It took me a while to figure out that long poll only works on a single user with Java SDK at this moment.

Is there an Java example code which can pull out the enterprise admin event? Enterprise events are in the API already, though Java SDK hasn't implements such feature yet.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-in-an-enterprise

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a request on the github project.  https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/issues

You can watch the issue, or decide to become a contributor yourself.  If any of the contributors feel like working it into the SDK, then everyone that uses the SDK will benefit from it.